# Why are two bidirectional channels needed to implement the server protocol for a cell?

Tags: concurrency, f#, hopac

> It may seem odd that two bidirectional channels are needed to implement the protocol. Couldn't we use just a single channel and change the server loop to give and take on that single channel. Note that this is allowed in Hopac and poses no problem. A job cannot send itself a message using a channel in a single synchronous operation. Explain what would go wrong if there was only one channel instead of separate getCh and putCh channels. Hint: Consider a situation with multiple clients.

The above is from the [Hopac doc.](https://github.com/Hopac/Hopac/blob/master/Docs/Programming.md#example-storage-cells-using-alternatives)

Are the new users really expected to understand the finer points of library implementation at this point in the journey? I prefer it when the documentation gives answers rather than asks questions. What is the reason why using a single channel for both `take` and `get` is a bad idea?

```
module HopacExample

open System
open Hopac
open Hopac.Infixes

type Cell<'a> = {
    takeCh : Ch<'a>
    putCh : Ch<'a>
    }

let get c = Ch.take c.takeCh
let put c (x: 'a) = Ch.give c.putCh x

let cell x = Job.delay <| fun () ->
    let c = {takeCh = Ch (); putCh = Ch ()}
    let server x = 
        Alt.choose [
            Ch.take c.putCh
            Ch.give c.takeCh x ^->. x]

    Job.iterateServer x server >>-. c

run <| job {
    let! c = cell 1
    let print () = Job.start (get c >>- fun i -> printf "%i\n" i)
    let put i = Job.start (put c i)
    do! print()
    do! put 2
    do! print()
    do! put 3
    do! print()
    do! put 4
    do! print()
    do! put 5
    do! print()
    do! put 6
    do! print()
    }

Console.ReadKey()
```

```
2
3
4
4
5
6
```

```
module HopacExample2

open System
open Hopac
open Hopac.Infixes

let get c = Ch.take c
let put c (x: 'a) = Ch.give c x

let cell x = Job.delay <| fun () ->
    let c = Ch ()
    let server x = 
        Alt.choose [
            Ch.take c
            Ch.give c x ^->. x]

    Job.iterateServer x server >>-. c

run <| job {
    let! c = cell 1
    let print () = Job.start (get c >>- fun i -> printf "%i\n" i)
    let put i = Job.start (put c i)
    do! print()
    do! put 2
    do! print()
    do! put 3
    do! print()
    do! put 4
    do! print()
    do! put 5
    do! print()
    do! put 6
    do! print()
    }

Console.ReadKey()
```

```
5
5
5
5
5
6
```

There are some differences, but nothing I would not attribute to vagaries of concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you need two channels is to force the users to go through the server. You'd be able to tell what the problem with using just a single channel is if you removed the server entirely. With just a single channel, the clients might bypass the server and communicate to each other directly.

```
module HopacExample2

open System
open Hopac
open Hopac.Infixes

let get c = Ch.take c
let put c (x: 'a) = Ch.give c x

let cell x = 
    let c = Ch ()
    Job.start (put c x) >>-. c

run <| job {
    let! c = cell 1
    let print () = Job.start (get c >>- fun i -> printf "%i\n" i)
    let put i = Job.start (put c i)
    for i=2 to 6 do
        do! print()
        do! put i
    }

Console.ReadKey()
```